# Attempting to use .sort inside of .each

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

First time poster.  I am looking at a nested array. My objective is to find the smallest value of each array then return the smallest values as a new array. I understand my issue is `.sort` isn't actually happening. Why isn't it sorting each iteration and how can I fix it?

edit: found my issue! I *was* sorting the array, but after that line the array goes back to normal. What I needed to do was assign a local variable for small.sort then add the first element of that variable to the array.

```
array = [
  [3, 5, 7, 1, 2],
  [98, 35, 2, 34],
  [88, 37, 5, 6]
]
  
smallest_array = []

array.each do |small|
  small.sort
  smallest_array << small[0]
end

smallest_array


expected: [1, 2, 5]
got: [3, 98, 88]
```

Comment: What about `array.map(&:min)`? __Note:__ your code not working, please fix.

Comment: What makes you think `sort` isn't actually happening? I don't see anything in your code that would suggest that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is inside these 2 lines:

```rb
small.sort
smallest_array << small[0]
```

[`#sort`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sort) is not change the `small`, but returns a new array,

so to fix it, you can do it in two ways:

1st way:

```rb
sorted_small = small.sort
smallest_array << sorted_small[0]
```

2nd way:

```rb
small.sort!
smallest_array << small[0]
```

Both ways will work, as in first case you assign new array returned from `#sort` to variable. In second [`#sort!`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/sort%21) will change `small` array.

P.S.

Some refactoring suggestion with [`#map`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/map) and [`#min`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/min)

```rb
smallest_array = array.map { |small| small.min }
```

Comment: I completely forgot about #min. Thank you! I ended up going with the first method of assigning a variable to .sort but I'll keep these things in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`Array#sort` is non-destructive: it returns a *new* array that has the same elements as the original one but in sorted order. You never save it anywhere, so it is discarded. You could have used `smallest_array << small.sort[0]` and it would work.

`Array#sort!` is the destructive version. Your code would also work if you change `small.sort` to `small.sort!`, but it would also change your original array. Sometimes this is what you want, but such a side effect would probably not be appreciated if you just want to know the smallest elements in sub-arrays.

However, you could also use `min` instead of `sort` here. In fact the whole thing can be written much more compactly as

```
smallest_array = array.map(&:min)
```